# Is there a URL validator on .Net?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, url

Is there a method to validate URLs in .Net, ASP.Net, or ASP.Net MVC?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use the [`Uri.TryCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.trycreate.aspx) to validate an URL:

```
public bool IsValidUri(string uri)
{
    Uri validatedUri;
    return Uri.TryCreate(uri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out validatedUri);
}
```

The comments suggest that `TryCreate` just moves the exception handling one level down. However, I checked the source code and found that this is not the case. There is no try/catch inside `TryCreate`, it uses a custom parser which should not throw.

Comment: This is better than the try/catch implementations suggested.

Comment: Although it's just burying the try/catch one more level down, where you don't have to see it.

Comment: great-llama, that's true, but it is easier to read the code when using this syntax.

Comment: I just did a simple perf test looping 1000 times for this & Mehrdad's approach, using only 1 invalid url and found this one signifcantly faster (8000X faster). I'd be interested in some other results if someone wants to be more detailed (multiple URLs etc...)

Comment: @Nathan Koop: This method is not available in .NET < 2.0. If you're using .NET 2.0+ you should prefer this method. If performance is a concern, you should be using Regex since Uri.TryCreate also does the check by catching the exception (unlike Int32.TryParse). I doubt it's 8000X faster, however!

Comment: It seemed really like too big of a difference to me too, but I didn't want to spend a bunch of time looking into it right now. Good  point about .NET versions & regex.

Comment: There is no try/catch inside TryCreate, but there is inside CreateHelper, which is called internally by TryCreate. So great_llama was correct, except the try/catch is moved two levels down, and some extra checks are done before the try/catch, so TryCreate may not always hit the try/catch block in all circumstances.

Comment: Well, if we believe the source comment the parser should throw only in rare unforeseen cases. ("A precaution since custom Parser should never throw in this case.")

Comment: Fair enough. I was using Reflector, so I missed out on the comment.

Comment: Is this anyhow different from using [`Uri.IsWellFormedUriString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx)?

Comment: **Warning**: One thing that this type of validation *does* account for is javascript injection: `javascript:alert('hacked')`. So, a check for  javascript protocols is important!

Comment: This response is overrated, any thing you put like for example "qwerty" will be validated as an Url, because really this methodology will not check for an Url. See @Arjan answer those people who are searching for a real url validation.

Comment: @ElektroStudios: It all really depends on what you want to check. If you only want to accept absolute URLs you obviously need to change the second parameter to `UriKind.Absolute`. If you want to accept relative URLs (as described by https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1808) as well my example just works fine. (Note that your example "qwerty" is a perfectly valid *relative* URL according to RFC1808).

Answer (score 48):

The answers provided thusfar do not check for a scheme, allowing all kinds of unwanted input, which could make you vulnerable for javascript injection (see the comment of TheCloudlessSky).

An URI is just a unique identification of a object. "C:\Test" is a valid URI.

In my project I used the following code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Validates a URL.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="url"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private bool ValidateUrl(string url)
{
    Uri validatedUri;

    if (Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri validatedUri)) //.NET URI validation.
    {
        //If true: validatedUri contains a valid Uri. Check for the scheme in addition.
        return (validatedUri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || validatedUri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Define which schemes you will allow and change the code accordingly.

Comment: +1, This is the best answer and also the unique that really answers the question "how to validate an Url", an **URL**!.

Comment: Your method validates strings like Http://Ftp://www.google.com, witch doesnt makes sense at all =/

Answer (score 31):

You can use Uri.IsWellFormedUriString, no need to create your own function for that:

```
public static bool IsWellFormedUriString(string uriString, uriKind uriKind);
```

Where uriKind can be:

```
UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute 
UriKind.Absolute
UriKind.Relative
```

For more info see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is a URL validator for .Net

Answer (score 3):

In case you need the nice code in VB.Net from Arjan

```
    'Validates a URL.
    Function ValidateUrl(url As String) As Boolean
        Dim validatedUri As Uri = Nothing
        If (Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, validatedUri)) Then
            Return (validatedUri.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttp Or validatedUri.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
        End If
        Return False
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

A faster way (probably) than using try/catch functionality would be to use Regex. If you had to validate 1000s of URLs catching the exception multiple times would be slow.

Here's [a link to sample Regex](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=1854)- use Google to find more.

Comment: somehow i doubt that. regexes, even compiled are not especially fast. even if you could ever write one that was accurate.

Comment: Kris- perhaps you don't understand how expensive throw exceptions can be- they are very slow if done in a big loop.

Comment: RichardOD - the sample regex you listed works for some URL's, but fails on the following 100% valid URL. Like I said, harder to get right. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc5dc32d(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I guess if performance was a concern you could use Regex as the first method. If the Regex fails then switch to Uri.TryCreate. When I use Regex I usually write a bunch of unit tests to check the fringe cases.

Answer (score 0):

#### ASP.Net Core Model Validation

In ASP.Net Core, is common to have the validation as part of model binding (hence, called model validation in official documents)

Let's say you have an endpoint like:

```
public AppController: ControllerBase
{
      public async Task<IActionResult> GetValues(InputDto input) { ... }
}
```

And your InputDto model is:

```
public class InputDto
{
      public string DownloadLink {get; set;}
}
```

And your requirement is to validate that the given value for `DownloadLink` should be a well-formed URL.
You can use  [built-in attributes](https://the%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#built-in-attributes) which are designed for this purpose:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class InputDto
{
    [Url]  
    public string DownloadLink {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
static bool IsValidUri(string urlString) {
   try {
      new Uri(urlString);
      return true;
   } catch {
      return false;
   }
}
```