# Regular Expression for URL

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I have one asp.net application, in which i have one text box for entering home page url. By default this text box contains **http://**. If the user entered additional text rather than the existing text, it will make the validation. Otherwise leave it as it is. How it possible? Please help me by providing the regular expression for resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this expression

```
^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?$
```

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx#paght000001_commonregularexpressions

Or this mechanism in code behind

```
public bool IsValidUri(string uri)
{
  Uri validatedUri;
  return Uri.TryCreate(uri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out validatedUri);
}
```

Posted by 0xA3 here [Is there a URL validator on .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927847/is-there-a-url-validator-on-net)

HTH

Comment: this regular expression cannot validate such URLs as `http://президент.рф` and they are used (valid?) in Russia. And for `TryCreate` I wonder does it try to establish connection?

Comment: Good point for international software. Apache's implementation doesn't seem to be international either. However, TryCreate actually escapes the international characters and supports IRI's from RFC 3987. Read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx. TryCreate only validates, it doesn't create a connection.

Answer (score 1):

Validating URLs is not an easy task as it may seem. When writing such regular expressions you should keep in mind all the constraints. I've never seen an expression able to validate whether url is valid or not. F.i. there are URLs with local characters such `http://президент.рф` and it's not valid according to the regular experssion suggested by the MSDN. However it may be helpful to take a look at the [Apache's UrlValidator](http://kickjava.com/src/org/apache/commons/validator/UrlValidator.java.htm)