# How to check that a uri string is valid

Tags: c#, .net, uri

How do you check that a uri string is valid (that you can feed it to the Uri constructor)?

So far I only have the following but for obvious reasons I'd prefer a less brute way:

```
    Boolean IsValidUri(String uri)
    {
        try
        {
            new Uri(uri);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I tried Uri.IsWellFormedUriString but it doesn't seem to like everything that you can throw at the constructor. For example:

```
String test = @"C:\File.txt";
Console.WriteLine("Uri.IsWellFormedUriString says: {0}", Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(test, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
Console.WriteLine("IsValidUri says: {0}", IsValidUri(test));
```

The output will be:

```
Uri.IsWellFormedUriString says: False
IsValidUri says: True
```

**Update/Answer**

The Uri constructor uses kind Absolute by default. This was causing a discrepancy when I tried using Uri.TryCreate and the constructor. You do get the expected outcome if you match the UriKind for both the constructor and TryCreate.

Comment: **See Also**: [Is there a URL validator on .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/927847/1366033)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

A well-formed URI implies conformance with certain RFCs. The local path in your example is not conformant with these. Read more in the [`IsWellFormedUriString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx) documentation.

A false result from that method does not imply that the `Uri` class will not be able to parse the input. While the URI input might not be RFC conformant, it still can be a valid URI.

**Update**: And to answer your question - as the Uri documentation shows, there is a static method called [`TryCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131572.aspx) that will attempt exactly what you want and return true or false (and the actual `Uri` instance if true).

Comment: The question is "How do you check that a uri string is valid (that you can feed it to the Uri constructor)?"

Comment: TryCreate doesn't really tell you if a string will be accepted by the constructor. See Update.

Comment: @Manuel: that doesn't make sense at all - the outcome of `TryCreate` and the `Uri` constructor should be identical - try to pass the `UriKind` like you did for `TryCreate`.

Comment: You're right. The constructor uses the default kind Absolute. Thanks.

Comment: According to .Net sources [the IsWellFormedUriString method contains the TryCreate method call plus extra checks](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/UriExt.cs,24b1613846e7f879), therefore I prefer to use the IsWellFormedUriString method as more powerful for such tasks.

Comment: `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("http://dasda", UriKind.Absolute)` return `true`.

Comment: @JokeHuang That's what I would expect, because `http//dasda` is an absolute URI that refers to a host named `dasda` on the local network.

Comment: @JokeHuang In particular, RFC 3986 is very explicit that the name resolution for URIs that specify a registered name for the authority part of the URI is not expected to use specific lookup method (ie. DNS), and can use any OS-dependent method like NetInfo or yellow pages ( yes, that is in  RFC 3986, 3.2.2 Host - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#page-11 :-) )

Answer (score 69):

Since the accepted answer doesn't provide an explicit example, here is some code to validate URIs in C#:

```
Uri outUri;

if (Uri.TryCreate("ThisIsAnInvalidAbsoluteURI", UriKind.Absolute, out outUri)
   && (outUri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || outUri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps))
{
    //Do something with your validated Absolute URI...
}
```

Comment: Don't trust Uri.TryCreate function! This will also allow bad URLs. Try this 'http:// http:// google.com/page' (remove spaces). This URL pass the TryCreate function, but it's wrong.

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever You are correct that it parses as valid what you mentioned, but this is technically not wrong. The explanation in English: using the http protocol (**http://**), connect to the DNS entry for "http" (http://**http**) using an explicit (but omitted) port (http://http**:**) - so I'll assume the default for the protocol; you supplied an empty first level folder (http://http:**//**) but I know what you meant ;) followed by a path segment "google.com" (http://http://**google.com/**) and then the resource "page" (http://http://google.com/**page**)

Answer (score 11):

Assuming we only want to support absolute URI and HTTP requests, here is a function that does what you want:

```
public static bool IsValidURI(string uri)
{
    if (!Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(uri, UriKind.Absolute))
        return false;
    Uri tmp;
    if (!Uri.TryCreate(uri, UriKind.Absolute, out tmp))
        return false;
    return tmp.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || tmp.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
}
```

Comment: According to .Net sources [your second check **!Uri.TryCreate(uri, UriKind.Absolute, out tmp)** is redundant because the IsWellFormedUriString method already contains the TryCreate method call](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/UriExt.cs,24b1613846e7f879)

Comment: The second check is needed to make the third (and final) check possible. Without it, there is no `tmp`. The first step is arguably redundant in this instance...

Answer (score 4):

In my case I just wanted to test the uri, I don't want to slow down the application testing the uri.

```
Boolean IsValidUri(String uri){
  return Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(uri, UriKind.Absolute);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try it:

```
private bool IsValidUrl(string address)
    {
        return Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(address, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case the uri argument is an absolute path which refers to a file location, so as per the doc of the method it returns false. Refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx)

Comment: I'm using UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute so it shouldn't matter. Either way it doesn't work with UriKind.Relative or UriKind.Absolute so no luck there.