# c# building strings domains

Tags: c#, web-scraping, stringbuilder

I am trying to download images. Their link may be `image.png` or `http://www.example.com/image.png`.

I made the image.png be added to the host and passed it to a list. So image.png is now `http://www.example.com/image.png`

But if the other type is used what I get is `http://www.example.com//http://www.example.com/image.png`

All I need is to get the string after the third slash. Here is some code I am tried to use:

```
try
{
    path = this.txtOutput.Text + @"\" + str4 + etc;
    client.DownloadFile(str, path);
}
catch(Exception e)
{

    var uri = new Uri(str);
    String host = (String) uri.Host;
    String pathToFile = "http://" + host + "/";

    int len = pathToFile.Length;

    String fin = str.Substring(len, str.Length - len);

    path = this.txtOutput.Text + @"\" + str4 + etc;
    client.DownloadFile(fin, path);
}
```

Comment: What variable equals: http://www.example.com//http://www.example.com/image.png?

Comment: ah sorry the var str = http://www.example.com/image.png or just image.png depending on the site

Answer (score 1):

What are these variables all about, like `str4`, `etc` and so on? Instead of the try catch you could check wheter the string is a valid uri. Give a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835269/how-to-check-that-a-uri-string-is-valid). Try to debug you code line on line and check every single variable, then you will see which line makes the mistake.

EDIT

If I understodd you right, then this would be your solution:

```
        string wrongResult = "example.com//http://www.example.com/image.png";
        string shouldResult = "example.com/image.png";

        int listIndexOfHttp = wrongResult.LastIndexOf("http:");
        string correctResult = wrongResult.Substring(listIndexOfHttp);
```

When not please describe more specific from where you get this and it is always the same structure? or alaways different?

Comment: I just need to turn http://www.example.com//http://www.example.com/image.png into http://www.example.com/image.png stackoverflow took out the htt p