# I get error when using a valid Uri constructor

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, uri, .net-6.0

Im new to C# and am struggling to understand this: I'm trying to use one of the .NET 6.0 Uri constructors, namely this one:
`Uri(Uri baseUri, string? relativeUri);`

My code looks like this:

```
string baseUrl = "https://example.com";
string? route = null;
Uri test = new Uri(baseUrl, route);
```

But I get this error:

```
'route' may be null here. 
Argument 2: cannot convert from string to bool
```

Comment: There is no `Uri` constructor taking two string parameters, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.-ctor. You propbably meant `new Uri(new Uri(baseUrl), route);`

Comment: your second paramaeter should be bool and not string. For more clarity Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835269/how-to-check-that-a-uri-string-is-valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Uri(Uri baseUri, string? relativeUri);

Okay, but you did not do that. You passed `(string, string?)`.

If you want to call the `(Uri, string?)` constructor, do so:

```
Uri baseUrl = new Uri("https://example.com");
string? route = null;
Uri test = new Uri(baseUrl, route);
```

The error message you get is from the compiler picking the closest overload from what you have given it, which would be `(string, bool)`. And since your second parameter is not a `bool`, you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

your second parameter should be bool and not string
Check here for more:
[How to check that a uri string is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835269/how-to-check-that-a-uri-string-is-valid)

Mark Correct or Accepted if you get your answer.